# Log4J configuration not displaying Spring Transaction and other logs in JBoss AS7

Tags: java, logging, log4j, jboss7.x, spring-transactions

Following is my log4j.properties:

```
log4j.rootLogger=ALL, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %p [%c] - %m%n


log4j.logger.org.springframework=ALL
log4j.logger.app.dev.ems=ALL
log4j.logger.org.springframework.transaction=ALL
```

I have mentioned the `log4jConfigLocation` in the web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/resources/log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
```

And also defined its listener class:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

But I am unable to see the Spring Transaction log in console. Also from a class: `app.dev.ems.web.wicket.page.home.HomePage` when I am doing:

```
Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

public HomePage() {     
    logger.debug("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<JYM>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");//if logger.info is used then it is showing.       
}
```

This is also not displaying that log. I am in Wicket Application and I have set:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>configuration</param-name>
    <param-value>DEVELOPMENT</param-value>
</init-param>
```

While defining the WicketServlet.

I am unable to find the problem. Any information will be very helpful to me.

NB: If you want me to post the applicationContext.xml I can do that. Th Transaction is Annotation driven.

---

I have log4j-1.2.14, slf4j-api-1.6.1, slf4j-log4j12-1.4.2 added. And I am using JBoss AS-7.1.0-Final.

In other SO thread I saw that this is problem with JBoss, and as per the instruction given there I have added jboss-deployment-structure.xml in WEB-INF(also tried with META-INF):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

And defined a bean in applicationContext.xml which will load the log4j.properties:

```
<bean id="log4jInitializer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetClass" value="org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="initLogging" />
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:/app/dev/ems/web/log4j.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

But unfortunately it didn't worked.

Comment: Are you running in stand alone mode or domain mode? JBoss now defaults to sl4j. Also did you add the logger in the logging subsystem in standalone.xml or domain.xml?

Comment: @CoolBeans I didn't add anything. I just downloaded the JBoss-AS-7.1.0-Final and deployed my war into standalone/deployments folder. I saw in some other SO thread that to use jboss-deployment-structure.xml, so I followed that. I have modified my question to describe those steps.

Comment: Spring use common-logging so you have to first disable it. Have a read to the [Logging section of Spring Reference Mannual](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html#d0e748).

Comment: @Cole after excluding common-logging do I need to take the steps like jboss-deployment-structure.xml?

Comment: @TapasBose I'm not familiar with JBoss configuration, so you have to try it yourself. Anyway, my project use slf4j+logback under jetty, and by following the spring reference instruction, I successfully see spring logs.

Comment: I found you still miss the slf4j bridge library for common-logging

Comment: @Cole are you referencing log4j-over-slf4j.jar?

Comment: JBoss AS 7 does not default to slf4j. It uses JBoss Logging.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins can you tell me how can I solve this problem? I have added jboss-deployment-structure.xml in WEB-INF, but no luck :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` exclusion should be working. If it's not, it could be the location of your configuration file. I'm not familiar with Spring so maybe adding the `<context-param/>` is a typical way to specify the location of the log configuration.

You might want to try to move your `log4j.properties` to the to the `WEB-INF/classes` or `META-INF` directory of your archive. Also you make sure you're including the log4j library in your deployment.

FWIW the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` will no longer be needed for logging configurations. It's not in a release yet, but it is in the upstream source.

Since it seems you're looking for a way to turn on debugging you need to do two things. You need to set a handler to allow debug messages to come through. You also need to setup a logger that will allow at least debug if not all messages to come through.

For example in your case you would create a logger like so.

```
<logger category="app.dev.ems.web.wicket" />
```

That will create a logger that will log at all levels. Now create a handler, or change a previously defined handler to accept debug messages.

Another example would be creating a file handler for your specific logger that will print your log message into a file.

```
<file-handler name="myFileHandler>
    <level name="DEBUG"/>
    <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="my-log.log"/>
</file-handler>
```

Now create your logger and assign the handler to it.

```
<logger category="app.dev.ems.web.wicket">
    <handlers>
        <handler name="myFileHandler/>
    </handlers>
<logger>
```

Now all log messages passed through a logger that has a category of `app.dev.ems.web.wicket.*` will print to that file in addition to the handlers attached to the root-logger. If you don't want to see these in the default `server.log` or on the console you can add the `use-parent-handler="false"` attribute to the logger.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. My aim was to see the transaction logs. And now I can see that. What I did, I have modified the standalone.xml file resides in standalone/configuration. I changed some parts of the Logging subsystem:

The console-handler:

```
<console-handler name="CONSOLE">
   <level name="INFO"/>
   <formatter>
       <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
   </formatter>
 </console-handler>
```

changed to

```
<console-handler name="CONSOLE">
   <level name="DEBUG"/>
   <formatter>
       <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
   </formatter>
 </console-handler>
```

And the root-logger

```
<root-logger>
   <level name="INFO"/>
   <handlers>
      <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
      <handler name="FILE"/>
   </handlers>
</root-logger>
```

changed to

```
<root-logger>
   <level name="DEBUG"/>
   <handlers>
      <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
      <handler name="FILE"/>
   </handlers>
</root-logger>
```

And that works. Now I can see the DEBUG log in console. :)

Comment: Ah, all you wanted to do was turn on debug logging? That wasn't very clear in your original question :-) You can remove the level from your console-handler. Also if you were to create a specific logger, e.g. `<logger category="app.dev.ems.web.wicket"><level name="DEBUG"/></logger>`, you then wouldn't have to set the root logger to a debug level.

Comment: Thanks. Primarily what I wanted is to see the Transaction log. Then I found that simple log.debug("something"); is not displaying, but log.info("something"); does. Now the problem is solved. Can you add this particular comment in your answer? Thanks again :)