# Unable to capture spring framework logs on jboss server

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, logging, jboss

I am launching our applications on Jboss, they are successfully up and running abd able to see logs for jboss or other springframework logs. I have the springframework logs printing for one application and not on the other one. I have common standalone.xml logging setup for both.

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.1">
            <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
                <level name="DEBUG"/>
                <formatter>
                    <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
                </formatter>
            </console-handler>
            <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE">
                <formatter>
                    <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
                </formatter>
                <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
                <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
                <append value="true"/>
            </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
            <logger category="org.springframework">
                <level name="DEBUG"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="com.arjuna">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="sun.rmi">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="jacorb">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="jacorb.config">
                <level name="ERROR"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="org.jboss.security">
                <level name="TRACE"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="org.springframework.security">
                <level name="DEBUG"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="org.springframework.beans">
                <level name="DEBUG"/>
            </logger>
            <root-logger>
                <level name="DEBUG"/>
                <handlers>
                    <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                    <handler name="FILE"/>
                </handlers>
            </root-logger>
        </subsystem>
```

Can some one provide pointers or suggestions for possible reasons.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Log4J configuration not displaying Spring Transaction and other logs in JBoss AS7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10372720/log4j-configuration-not-displaying-spring-transaction-and-other-logs-in-jboss-as)

Comment: We are using jboss logging, for internal logging we use our custom logging api. This is common for all applications internally.

Comment: Is this a Spring Boot application that you had built a WAR from?  I found in one application I was working, that the log levels I had set months prior in my application.properties file in the WAR were overriding all my efforts in the standalone.xml for logging.